# PSQL COPY tables to CSV - Data consistency on production database

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4, consistency, pg-dump

I'm doing a dump of a database to separate CSV files, using the shell script below :

```
PGENGINE=$PGHOME/bin
PGPASSWORD=$1 $PGENGINE/psql -p $2 -h $3 -U $4 -Atc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='public'" $5 |\
while read TBL; do
    echo "Exporting table "$TBL
    PGPASSWORD=$1 $PGENGINE/psql -p $2 -h $3 -U $4 -c "COPY public.$TBL TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '"$SEPARATEUR_CSV"'" $5 > /$ROOT_PATH/$6/$TBL.csv
    echo -e $TBL ": Export done\n"
done
```

This works fine on my test database, but I am concerned about what will happen running it on a production database.

I saw many topics saying that pg_dump acquires a lock on data but I don't know about psql COPY, including the fact that I'm making a loop over all tables. I need to be sure that if a user updates one of my tables, the COPY command will still get the right data and the right FKs.

My questions:

1. Do you think it is a proper way to do it ? Is a stored procedure safer for data consistency?
2. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? (since this production database is quite large - some tables are over 30 million rows).

Comment: You are essentially copying what `pg_dump` is doing. The "lock" that `pg_dump` takes is the same as a plain SELECT will acquire and what your COPY statement also acquires. It's only there to prevent concurrent DDL statements on that table, nothing else will be blocked.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. Is there any way to lock all tables or all related tables (concerning FKs) ? Or maybe could I achieve this with a stored procedure ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you think you need to lock all tables?

Comment: Let's say there is a table A with a FK to a table B. If some user can modify table A when B is locked and vice versa, there may be some FK conflicts when I will try to reload database from the CSV file created. Isn't it ?

Comment: `pg_dump` creates a **consistent** dump of the database (as of the moment when it started). There is no need to prevent changes to the database.

Comment: Ok, I guess PostgreSQL is well done for this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consistent read across tables in a live database  is achieved by starting a transaction in the REPEATABLE READ isolation mode and ending it when all is read. Your script must be transformed so that there is only one `psql` invocation, looking like this:

```
psql [connection arguments] << EOF
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
\copy table1 TO file1.csv
\copy table2 TO file2.csv
\copy table3 TO file3.csv
COMMIT;

EOF
```

Note `\copy` instead of `COPY`, as a consequence of having all grouped in the same psql invocation. `psql` itself routes each `\copy`'s data to each client-side output file.

Also it's a two-step workflow: first generate the above script (such as by looping in bash over the result of `psql -c 'select tablename....'` or any other method), then execute the script.

Why can't it be simplified to one step?

The loop cannot be implemented in the psql script because psql doesn't have loops, except somewhat with `\gexec`, but it's not applicable here because `\copy` is a meta-command, and `\gexec` handles only SQL commands.

The loop also cannot be implemented in plpgsql, unless changing the context of the question, because each output of `COPY TO STDOUT` would not be routed to a corresponding per-table client-side file. It would come back to the client as everything concatenated into a single stream. If using the SQL command `COPY TO file` it would work but you need to be superuser and the files end up on the server, not on the client.

Comment: To loop over tables of the database, will I need to do it in a stored procedure ?

Comment: You already have a loop over tables in your question. A stored procedure will not help at all. The point is, instead of calling psql with COPY in a loop, you build a script in that loop, and then when you're outside of that loop you execute that script. Once.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you. Maybe you should edit your answer to add this, so if someone checks the topic, this will be part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with this solution :

```
PGENGINE=$PGHOME/bin
    CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION=/$ROOT_PATH/plc/proc/tmp/dump_transaction.sql
    DOSSIER_DUMP_FICHIERS=/$ROOT_PATH/dump/dump_$6/dump_fichiers

    echo "BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;" > $CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION

    PGPASSWORD=$1 $PGENGINE/psql -p $2 -h $3 -U $4 -Atc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='public'" $5 |\
    while read TBL; do
        echo "\copy $TBL TO $DOSSIER_DUMP_FICHIERS/$TBL.csv WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';';" >> $CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION
        echo "\echo " >> $CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION
    done
    echo "COMMIT;" >> $CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION

    PGPASSWORD=$1 $PGENGINE/psql -p $2 -h $3 -U $4 -d $5 -f $CHEMIN_SCRIPT_TRANSACTION
```

I'm creating a script in a different file and then I use psql -f to play this script.